How to handle the loss function decrease at some points but bounce back to keep increasing when fine-tune LLaMA?
Preface
I am new to fine-tuning an LLM model on binary classification tasks. I have tried fine-tuning LLaMA 2 and 3 with the causal inference task (next token prediction) with PEFT LoRA and 4-bit quantization. The task that I have been trained on is using various prompts.

${Text}. ${Question}. ${Answer (Positive class or negative class)}
${Some context}. ${Question}. ${Answer (Positive class or negative class)}

The training arguments are here:
per_device_train_batch_size = 8
gradient_accumulation_steps = 4
optim = "paged_adamw_32bit"
save_steps = 100
logging_steps = 10
learning_rate = 1e-4
max_grad_norm = 0.3 # I have tried to use default max_grad_norm
max_steps = 1000
warmup_ratio = 0.03 # I have tried to use default warmup_ratio
lr_scheduler_type = "cosine_with_restarts" # I have tried it using "cosine" too

Here is the trainer:
trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_arguments,
    train_dataset=dataset,
    packing=True,
    dataset_text_field="id",
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    max_seq_length=1024,
    formatting_func=formatting_func,
)

Issues and Questions
The issue comes within the results. The loss function decreases after some steps, but after particular steps, the loss function keeps increasing (I supposed that LLaMA used cross entropy as the loss function). Is the issue within the LLM that I used (LLaMA) or what may cause the problem? and how to solve it.


The trainloss seems to be decreasing just fine with smaller learning_rates. To get started, I would try to lower the training rate with constant lr-scheduler

@SandroH I have tried to use a lower learning rate 4e-5 and 3e-5. It is better as it doesn't increase the training loss. It decreases about linearly from step 0 until step 120. But after step 120 until 1000, it stuck in ~1. Do you know what parameter is likely to make the training loss keep decreasing and doesn't stuck?

Seems starts to overfit. Have you tried early stopping? Does the performance on the lowest loss value acceptable? Or this is only training loss? Do you have validation loss?
